# Need to add the multiple records in grid when I click the add button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, extjs4

When I click the button I have to add the multiple records to the grid. But it adds only one record per time. That is, it adds one record; after that, it's only able to add the record.

Note that based on the radio button check edit happens.

Can anyone correct the code if is wrong?

```
tbar: [
                {
                    text: 'Add',
                    tooltip: 'Add Focus Market',
                    iconCls: 'icon-shift-add',
                    scope: me,
                    handler: function() {
                            addFocusMarket.call(this);
                    }
                }
            ],

plugins: [ this.mcmRowEditing ],
            viewConfig: {},
            listeners: {
                scope: me,
                validateedit: function(editor, e) {
                    var searchval = Ext.getCmp('searchGroup').getValue();
                    if(searchval.search_type == "CityPair" ) {
                        console.log("city pair update..");
                        if(e.newValues.Origin !== e.originalValues.Origin ||
                            e.newValues.Destination !== e.originalValues.Destination ||
                            e.newValues.CabinClass !== e.originalValues.CabinClass ||
                            e.newValues.StartAvailability.getDate() !== e.originalValues.StartAvailability.getDate() ||
                            e.newValues.EndAvailability.getDate() !== e.originalValues.EndAvailability.getDate()) {


                            if(!e.newValues.Origin) {
                                App.mcmShowMessageBox({
                                title: 'Important', 
                                message: 'Please set the Origin', 
                                time: 2000
                            });
                            return false; }

                            if(!e.newValues.Destination) {
                                App.mcmShowMessageBox({
                                title: 'Important', 
                                message: 'Please set the Destination', 
                                time: 2000
                            });
                            return false; }

                            if(!e.newValues.CabinClass) {
                                App.mcmShowMessageBox({
                                title: 'Important', 
                                message: 'Please enter a valid CabinClass', 
                                time: 2000
                            });
                            return false; }
                            e.newValues.Origin = e.newValues.Origin.toUpperCase();
                            e.newValues.Destination = e.newValues.Destination.toUpperCase();
                            e.record.set('Origin', e.newValues.Origin);
                            e.record.set('Destination', e.newValues.Destination);
                            e.record.set('CabinClass', e.newValues.CabinClass);
                            e.record.set('StartAvailability', e.newValues.StartAvailability);
                            e.record.set('EndAvailability', e.newValues.EndAvailability);

                            App.mcmAddCityPair({
                                focusmarketRecord: e.record, 
                                successCallback: function(obj) {
                                    e.record.data = obj;
                                    App.mcmFindCityPair(this.mcmSearchType, obj.Origin, obj.Destination, 
                                        obj.StartAvailability, obj.EndAvailability);
                                    this.mcmHasChanges = true;
                                }, 
                                successScope: this,
                                failureCallback: App.mcmTabReload,
                                failureScope: App
                            });
                      }
                    }

                    else if(searchval.search_type == "IndividualFlights") {
                        console.log("flight number update..");
                        if(e.newValues.Origin !== e.originalValues.Origin ||
                            e.newValues.Destination !== e.originalValues.Destination ||
                            e.newValues.CabinClass !== e.originalValues.CabinClass ||
                            e.newValues.FlightNumber !== e.originalValues.FlightNumber ||
                            e.newValues.StartAvailability.getDate() !== e.originalValues.StartAvailability.getDate() ||
                            e.newValues.EndAvailability.getDate() !== e.originalValues.EndAvailability.getDate()) {

                            if(!e.newValues.FlightNumber) {
                                App.mcmShowMessageBox({
                                title: 'Important', 
                                message: 'Please enter a valid FlightNumber', 
                                time: 2000
                            });
                            return false; }


                            if(!e.newValues.Origin) {
                                App.mcmShowMessageBox({
                                title: 'Important', 
                                message: 'Please set the Origin', 
                                time: 2000
                            });
                            return false; }

                            if(!e.newValues.Destination) {
                                App.mcmShowMessageBox({
                                title: 'Important', 
                                message: 'Please set the Destination', 
                                time: 2000
                            });
                            return false; }

                            if(!e.newValues.CabinClass) {
                                App.mcmShowMessageBox({
                                title: 'Important', 
                                message: 'Please enter a valid CabinClass', 
                                time: 2000
                            });
                            return false; }

                            e.newValues.Origin = e.newValues.Origin.toUpperCase();
                            e.newValues.Destination = e.newValues.Destination.toUpperCase();
                            e.record.set('Origin', e.newValues.Origin);
                            e.record.set('Destination', e.newValues.Destination);
                            e.record.set('CabinClass', e.newValues.CabinClass);
                            e.record.set('FlightNumber', e.newValues.FlightNumber);
                            e.record.set('StartAvailability', e.newValues.StartAvailability);
                            e.record.set('EndAvailability', e.newValues.EndAvailability);

                            App.mcmAddIndividaulFlight({
                                focusmarketRecord: e.record, 
                                successCallback: function(obj) {
                                    e.record.data = obj;
                                    App.mcmFindIndividualFlights(this.mcmSearchType, obj.Origin, obj.Destination, 
                                            obj.StartAvailability, obj.EndAvailability, obj.FlightNumber);
                                    this.mcmHasChanges = true;
                                }, 
                                successScope: this,
                                failureCallback: App.mcmTabReload,
                                failureScope: App
                            });
                        }

                    }

                }
            }




    var addFocusMarket = function(focusmarket) {
            this.mcmRowEditing.cancelEdit();
            var searchval = Ext.getCmp('searchGroup').getValue();
            console.log("add focus market" + focusmarket);
            if(searchval.search_type == "CityPair"){
                var record = new Sch.model.Resource({
                Id: 0, 
                Origin: focusmarket ? focusmarket.Origin : '',
                Destination: focusmarket ? focusmarket.Destination: '',
                CabinClass: focusmarket ? focusmarket.CabinClass: '',
                StartAvailability: focusmarket ? focusmarket.startAvailability: '', 
                EndAvailability: focusmarket ? focusmarket.endAvailability: ''
                });
                console.log("records-->"+record);
            }
            else if(searchval.search_type == "IndividualFlights"){
                var record = new Sch.model.Resource({
                Id: 0, 
                Origin: focusmarket ? focusmarket.Origin : '',
                Destination: focusmarket ? focusmarket.Destination: '',
                FlightNumber: focusmarket ? focusmarket.FlightNumber: '',
                CabinClass: focusmarket ? focusmarket.CabinClass: '',
                StartAvailability: focusmarket ? focusmarket.startAvailability: '', 
                EndAvailability: focusmarket ? focusmarket.endAvailability: ''
                });
                console.log("records-->"+record);
            }
            App.mcmFocusMarketStore.insert(0, record);
            this.mcmRowEditing.startEdit(0, 0);
            this.mcmHasChanges = true;
        };
```

Comment: This is a massive chunk of code. Is there any way you can put together a simple working example of this code at http://fiddle.sencha.com? That would go a long way toward other's helping debug your code.

Comment: @existdissolve my problem is I can able to add new row after update one row after that only I can able to insert another row.. I need to add each and every click of add button.. Like the sencha row editing example

Comment: Are you using the same ids each time? I can't tell but it looks like the id is the same every time. If so you will only see the first one, make sure the id is unique.

Comment: @theboulderer can you provide example..

Answer (score 0):

when you create your ID try using a unique ID. If you enter 0 for the id each time you create a record you will only see one record in the grid. You need to generate a unique id each time you could use Ext.id() or write your own.

var record = new Sch.model.Resource({
 **//RIGHT HERE THIS NEEDS TO BE UNIQUE//  Id: 0,** 
                Origin: focusmarket ? focusmarket.Origin : '',
                Destination: focusmarket ? focusmarket.Destination: '',
                CabinClass: focusmarket ? focusmarket.CabinClass: '',
                StartAvailability: focusmarket ? focusmarket.startAvailability: '', 
                EndAvailability: focusmarket ? focusmarket.endAvailability: ''
                });